# How to assert the user is logout in django.test.TestCase?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and now I'm strugging writing test code.

In a test case I want to check if the user is logout successfully.
Then how can I write assert?

Below is the tiny sample code.

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class TestLogin(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['myuserdata.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()

    def setUp(self):
        self.USER_ADMIN = {
            'email': "foo1@bar.com",
            'password': "foobar1234",
        }
        self.USER_PLAIN = {
            'email': "foo2@bar.com",
            'password': "foobar1234",
        }

    def test_login_success(self):
        login_result = self.client.login(
            email=self.USER_ADMIN['email'],
            password=self.USER_ADMIN['password'],
        )
        self.assertTrue(login_result)

        login_result = self.client.login(
            email=self.USER_PLAIN['email'],
            password=self.USER_PLAIN['password'],
        )
        self.assertTrue(login_result)

        self.client.logout()
        # self.assertFoobar(???)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the logout using your **logout** url.

```
response = self.client.get('/your/logout/url')
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

Comment: I've found my solution. But is it good way?

```python
self.client.logout()
response = self.client.get('/')
user = response.context['user']
self.assertFalse(user.is_authenticated)
```

Comment: This will work but seems like brute-force approach. One I have suggested have u tried?

Comment: @k-brahma, You can select the answer if it resolved your query. Thanks